# Etiqueta [golang] debería ser sinónimo de [go]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

A mi parecer, creo que la etiqueta [golang](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) debe ser sinónimo de [go](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go). Ambas hacen referencia al lenguaje de programación de Google.

Me he fijado en SOen y la tienen puesta como sinónimo, así que supongo que debería ser así.

¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Sin ninguna duda. Deben ser sinónimos. Esperaremos a ver si hay alguna voz en contra, y si no es asi las uniremos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He creado el sinonimo de etiqueta, quedando [go](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) como la principal, y realizado la combinación de preguntas.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias por tu tiempo @Pikoh :)